# Pass null to webservice number field?

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, soap, xml

**What does properly formed XML look like when attempting to pass in a null value for a number field?**

---

Let's say I have a SOAP endpoint defined as follows:

```
webservice static void save(MyObject__c record)
{
    // fancy upsert logic here
}
```

And my payload comes in looking like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope ...>
    <soapEnv:Header>
        <!-- header info -->
    </soapEnv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns0:save>
            <ns0:myObjectData>
                <ns0:Number_Field__c/>
                <!-- other fields -->
            </ns0:myObjectData>
        </ns0:save>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

The above payload is trying to save a record with `Number_Field__c=null`. Unfortunately, the endpoint generates this error message:

> '' is not valid for the type xsd:double

Entire response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>'' is not valid for the type xsd:double</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

To reiterate: **What does properly formed XML look like when attempting to pass in a null value for a number field?**

Comment: Not nearly experienced enough with xml/SOAP to give a proper answer, but I've seen xml errors reference something of the form `xsi:nil` before, and a cursory search indicates that this can be an attribute of an xml tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to specify null with xsl:nil:

```
<ns0:Number_Field__c xsl:nil="true" />
```

Comment: Will let you know results when I get them. Might be a day or few.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sure. By the way, this seems to be true in the AJAX toolkit, by reading the source code, so I'm pretty sure this is right.

Comment: Excellent. Yeah it looks right, just couldn't produce it on my own.

Comment: Also, check that you have a `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` attribute somewhere earlier in the xml to define the namespace prefix.